# How can I get today's timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I tried

```
$dtToday = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', date('Y-m-d'));
```

but when I output it

```
die($dtToday->format('d M Y g:i:s a'));
```

I still get the time eg "22 Jan 2011 4:53:59 pm". Why is that?

**UPDATE**

Ah... many people misunderstood me, my bad, I forgot to point out the main point. I created the date with just the date portion, I don't want the time. So I'd expect something like

```
22 Jan 2011 12:00:00 am
```

Comment: You did ask that the date be returned as `d M Y g:i:s a` so what's wrong with the output?

Comment: @Salman A, I created the date with now time, so I'd expect the time to be 12:00:00 am?

Comment: The title of this question is very confusing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can call [`->setTime(0, 0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) to zero out the time portion:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2011-01-22')->setTime(0, 0);
echo $date->format('d M Y g:i:s a');
// 22 Jan 2011 12:00:00 am
```

Answer (score 15):

See the documentation for [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

> If *format* does not contain the character ! then portions of the generated time which are not specified in *format* will be set to the current system time.

If you do the following function call, you'll get the result you expect:

```
$dtToday = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', date('Y-m-d'));
```

Answer (score 13):

Today's start timestamp

```
$todayStartTS = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', time()) . ' 00:00:00');
```

Comment: it should be ' 00:00:00' Don't forget the space.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by passing the current unix timestamp as the second parameter to the date function

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
```

Comment: the second parameter to date() defaults to time(), so date('Y-m-d') is sufficient.

Comment: actually its not the format, see my update. Basically I am asking why after creating the DateTime with just the date minus the time part, why do I still get the time? I want the date without the time portion

Answer (score 1):

Remove this part `g:i:s a` from your code.

Now, if you want a nice date formatted according to your local, i recommand you to use [`strftime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) function.

Comment: Sorry, I mean why after creating the DateTime without the time portion, why do I still get the time?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting "22 Jan 2011 4:53:59 pm" because those are the rules you format your date with :
d (day) : 22
M (Month) : Jan
Y (Year) : 2011
g (12-hour format) : 4
i (minutes): 53
s (seconds): 59
a (am/pm): pm
Be more speciffic about the format would you like your timestamp to have.
I suggest you take a peak at the [php date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I mean why after creating the DateTime without the time portion, why do I still get the time?

Answer (score 0):

Is it using UTC, or something?

I have a PHP version that gives me an error whenever I do something `date` related without first using `date_default_timezone_set`. Maybe that'll help you.